# How to access chrome dev tools on a chromebook from another machine

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, portforwarding, chromebook, gentoo

I recently followed many guides about how to get the chromebook into dev mode, allow modifications by making the linux OS writable and how the forwarding works. Also opened the firewall to allow any traffic. I've entered the `--remote-debugging-port=2253` and `--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0` to the `/etc/chrome-dev.conf` file. The reason I entered 0.0.0.0 is because to my understanding, chrome does not by default allow remote hosts to connect and is by default only listening to localhost. (This method worked on Ubuntu, macOS and windows devices.)

Now when I start chrome and browse to localhost:2253 I indeed get to see inspectable pages. However, I cannot access these from another machine. (Even with forwarding enabled)

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? The reason I want to access these pages is because I'm trying to run an automated remote test (with puppeteer) that takes screenshots while 'using' our application.

I've also tried to take another path and get node running on the chromebook without success. I tried doing this with NVM but When installing NVM it fails because of permissions errors. Even when running as sudo.

I hope someone can help me so I can remotely connect to the device with the chrome devtools.